# .htaccess redirect to 404 page using shared hosting with 2 different domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using 2 different domains on the same GoDaddy Hosting Plan. 
So I have a addon of my main domain **http://sethjfreeman.xyz** set to redirect to **http://relestalrabbitrescue.org**. So with it being set like this, I only have one .htaccess file that controls both domains.

The problem is, How do I redirect a non existent (404) page to 2 different domains. So if I type a non existent url on **http://sethjfreeman.xyz** it redirects to **http://sethjfreeman.xyz/404.html**. Same goes with **http://relestalrabbitrescue.org** and **http://relestalrabbitrescue.org/404.html**.

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 http://relestalrabbitrescue.org/404.html
```

Right now, If I type a non existent (404) page on **http://sethjfreeman.xyz**, it redirects to **http://relestalrabbitrescue.org/404.html**

*I know personally if I have access to visualize what's going on, it helps me problem solve. So if that's you too, here's some pictures of the hosting panel:* 
[image: hosting panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Just do that and it will redirect to the 404.html for the url you are using given that the file is in root folder in both sites